# position UITabBar at the top in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

Is it possible to position UITabBar at the top in swift and how? I can't position my UITabBar at the top of the view.

Comment: Are you talking about the tab bar of a `UITabBarController` or just a plain `UITabBar`?

Comment: Stackoverflow is no code writing service, please include some things you have tried. Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page on how to ask a "good" question.

Comment: Have a look at UISegmentedControls

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can hide tab bar and a custom view to the top of the screen.

It is hard to give you full code but I will try to help you to solve your situation.

1) Hide the tab bar that you have

2) create custome tar by using this example
http://blog.adambardon.com/how-to-create-custom-tab-bar-in-swift-part-1/

3) addsub view to your tabbarcontrollerview and give frame x = 0 , y = 0, width = screenwidth and height = 69

Hope this will help you

Comment: Your answer is unclear to me and seems to lack detail. Please include some further explanation.